# Problems with USB in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, usb, devices

After update from Ubuntu 18.04 (where everything worked correctly) to Ubuntu 20.04 I have a problem with USB:

```
08:59:20 kernel: usb 1-3: 2:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x1
08:59:20 kernel: usb 1-3: 2:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x1
08:59:13 kernel: usb 1-3: 1:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x81
08:19:31 kernel: usb 1-3: 2:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x1
08:05:53 kernel: usb 3-1.1: 1:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x81
08:03:57 kernel: usb 1-4: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
08:03:57 kernel: usb 1-4: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
08:03:56 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
08:03:37 kernel: usb 1-4: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
08:03:37 kernel: usb 1-4: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
08:03:37 kernel: usb 1-4: 2:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x1
08:03:37 kernel: usb 1-4: 1:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x81
08:03:31 kernel: usb 1-4: 2:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x1
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
08:03:31 kernel: 
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT4._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT4._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT4._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT2._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT2._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT4._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT4._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT1._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT1._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT2._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT2._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT1._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT1._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
08:03:31 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT5._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
08:03:31 kernel: integrity: Couldn't parse dbx signatures: -74
```

One visible problem maybe related with above is that microphone is detected but does not work for headphones connected via USB. I use matherboard: GigaByte Z77X-UD3H.

Answer (score 0):

have you solved this problem? I also encountered this when I update some software and restart. I noticed someone meet a similar issue and their problem is with their camera. I'm using inter realsense d435i recently and maybe that's the problem, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi - it looks like you're using the answer section to add a comment to the question. Please put questions in as comment, not answers. Sorry about the confusion :-)